# Wikitable scrapping using python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape all the tables in the following link of Wikipedia in general to get the episode number and name. But it stops near the first table and doesn't move around with the second one. I need some light on it.

**wiki_link : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_(season_20)#Episode_list**

**But the given data in table looks like this :**
[image]

***Basically I am trying to fetch the data in the rows with respect to the columns [ No.Overall [n1] & Title[n2] ]***

***[i.e   892  The Land of Wano! To the Samurai Country where Cherry Blossoms Flutter! ]***

***Required output in CSV like:**

[image]

**the code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.plotting import table
import requests
 
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_(season_20)#Episode_list"

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable'}).tbody
rows = table.find_all('tr')
columns = [v.text.replace('\n','') for v in rows[0].find_all('th')]
#print(len(rows))
#print(table)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
print(df)

for i in range(1,len(rows)):
    tds = rows[i].find_all('td')
    print(len(tds))
    if len(tds)==6:
        values1 = [tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text.replace('\n',''.replace('\xa0',''))]
        epi = values1[0]
        title = values1[1].split('Transcription:')
        titles = title[0]
        print(f'{epi}|{titles}')
    else:
        values2 = [td.text.replace('\n',''.replace('\xa0','')) for td in tds]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to go with your `BeautifulSoup` approach, select all the `<tr>` with class `vevent` and iterate the `ResultSet` to create a list of dicts that you can use to create a dataframe, ...:

```
[
    {
        'No.overall':r.th.text,
        'Title':r.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')[0].text.split('Transcription:')[0]
    } 
    for r in soup.select('tr.vevent')
]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_(season_20)#Episode_list"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            'No.overall':r.th.text,
            'Title':r.select('td:nth-of-type(2)')[0].text.split('Transcription:')[0]
        } 
        for r in soup.select('tr.vevent')
    ]
)
```

##### Output

| No.overall | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 892 | "The Land of Wano! To the Samurai Country where Cherry Blossoms Flutter!" |
| 893 | "Otama Appears! Luffy vs. Kaido's Army!" |
| 894 | "He'll Come! The Legend of Ace in the Land of Wano!" |
| 895 | "Side Story! The World's Greatest Bounty Hunter, Cidre!" |
| 896 | "Side Story! Clash! Luffy vs. the King of Carbonation!" |

...

Comment: Wow!! ur the timesaver here. Thanks for the time in helping me out here.

Answer (score 2):

I did a little bit of research regarding the webpage, and you don't need to go far when it comes to obtaining the tables. It seems like the data is split in 3 tables which we can concanate:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_(season_20)#Episode_list")[1:4]).reset_index()
```

With a little bit of data manipulation, we can extract the useful information:

```
episodes = pd.to_numeric(df['No.overall [n 1]'],errors='coerce').dropna()[:-2]
names = df.loc[(episodes.index+1),'No.overall [n 1]'].dropna()
```

Finally, we can create a new dataframe out of it:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({"Episode No.":episodes.values,
                       "Summary":names.values})
```

EDIT:

Given I originally considered the wrong column, getting the episode number and title is even easier:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Piece_(season_20)#Episode_list")[1:4])

df['Episode'] = pd.to_numeric(df['No.overall [n 1]'],errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset='Episode').rename(columns={'Title [n 2]':'Title'})[['Episode','Title']]
```

Returning:

```
   Episode                                              Title
1      892  "The Land of Wano! To the Samurai Country wher...
3      893  "Otama Appears! Luffy vs. Kaido's Army!"Transc...
5      894  "He'll Come! The Legend of Ace in the Land of ...
1      895  "Side Story! The World's Greatest Bounty Hunte...
3      896  "Side Story! Clash! Luffy vs. the King of Carb...
..     ...                                                ...
269   1027  "Defend Luffy! Zoro and Law's Sword Technique!...
271   1028  "Surpass the Emperor of the Sea! Luffy Strikes...
274   1029  "A Faint Memory! Luffy and Red-Haired's Daught...
275   1030  "The Oath of the New Era! Luffy and Uta"Transc...
278   1031  "Nami's Scream - The Desperate Death Race!"Tra...
```

Comment: Wow!! ur the timesaver here. Thanks for the time in helping me out here... But this method is fetching only the summary tag I would like to fetch just the episode no and the title.

Comment: Please let me know if this approach is useful, because while BeautifulSoup is different, it's not always the best solution for working with tabular data